# click a button and change image not smoothly in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, safari, onclick

I have an interface with many buttons, when one clicks the buttons, I used jquery to toggle the button image. something like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
   $(".button").html("<img src="...">");
});
```

All work fine. In Firefox, it would just immediately change button, looks very nice. But, in Chrome and Safari, when you click the button (or use other function update the button automatically, effectively very similar code: .html("...")), the button will flash, basically when it swap image, there is a blank moment there.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried preloading the second image? (Also, in my opinion it is neater to change the existing element's `src` attribute rather than replacing the entire element.)

Comment: typo adeneo, it is <img...>, I did it rightly in the code

Comment: thank you @nnnnnn, how do I preload this?

Comment: Typically I use position absolute to position two images on top of each other, then change the bottom one, then remove the top one from the DOM. alternatively you can try changing the src rather than the whole tag – if you add a CSS transition you'll get an animated cross fade…

Comment: So do you want the image to not display inside the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could do..

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(800,function(){
    $(this).text("<img src='img.jpeg'>");
    $(this).fadeIn(800);
  })
});
```